# changing SSMS settings via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, configuration, powershell

in order to enable the dark theme to SSMS (not available on the picture below as you see):

[image]

following this webpage:

[SQL SERVER Management Studio 18 - Enable Dark Theme - SQL Authority with Pinal Dave](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/09/12/sql-server-management-studio-18-enable-dark-theme/)

there are clear instructions as how to add the `dark`theme to SSMS. It works, but needs to be done manually.

[image]

now on this site below, there is the same set of instructions `plus` a way to get it done via powershell, as I have added here below, and it works, but [powershell](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/275050/22336) needs to be [run as administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28007/22336).

[Setting up the dark theme in SQL Server management studio (sqlshack.com)](https://www.sqlshack.com/setting-up-the-dark-theme-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

Depending on the version of SSMS, copy the appropriate script into the clipboard, paste it in PowerShell and hit Enter to execute it:

SSMS 2016

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef') -replace '\[\`$RootKey\`$\\Themes\\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}\]', '//[`$RootKey`$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]' | Out-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef'"
```

SSMS 17

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef') -replace '\[\`$RootKey\`$\\Themes\\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}\]', '//[`$RootKey`$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]' | Out-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef'"
```

SSMS 18

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef') -replace '\[\`$RootKey\`$\\Themes\\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}\]', '//[`$RootKey`$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]' | Out-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef'"
```

[Powershell](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54545/22336) as administrator running the command above:

[image]

Now my question, I am not sure whether it is possible or not.
Basically I would like to find out where these SSMS settings are saved, and change them preferably via powershell:

1. set the colour Theme as `Dark`
2. Items shown on the windows menu - currently 10, I would like to change that to 24

is it at all possible?

I have many servers where SSMS lives, and I would like to set them all to the same settings.

I am wondering if I could get this done [using SendKeys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197392/22336).

that added the `dark` theme - made it available for me to choose it as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use `Invoke-Command` to execute it on all servers remotely, you would need to execute as a user that has local admin rights on all those servers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft),

I used procmon and could find the settings are stored in the below regedit section,

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell\General

MRUListItemCount

WindowMenuItemCount
```

Change these values to 1-24

Answer (score 1):

You could use Process Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to discover where SSMS stores these settings.

Comment: Thank you David, `Process Monitor` is really very useful